# How do I remove the space or not have space in between the spans in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

Ok so if you do:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span6"></div><!--span6 END-->
    <div class="span6"></div><!--span6 END-->


   </div><!--row END-->
```

picture that as 2 red boxes both taking 50% of the screen.. but every time I do this the span6 has a margin our in between each other and the row above it... How do I make it so that there is no margin above or in between the spans .. I want them to touch above and to the sides.

Comment: What about adding `margin: 0px;` to your stylesheet?

Comment: nope iv tryed to add .span6{margin:0; padding:0; border:0;} in my style and still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably don't want to override all `.span6` elements, I'd suggest the following:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6" style="margin: 0px; background-color: red; width: 50%;">foo</div><!--span6 END-->
    <div class="span6" style="margin: 0px; background-color: blue; width: 50%;">bar</div><!--span6 END-->
</div><!--row END-->
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dolorem/xuywN/)

**EDIT**:

As `.row-fluid` uses `width: 100%` and `.row-fluid .span6` uses `width: 48.93617021276595%;`, you also need to change width of those divs. See updated code and fiddle.

Comment: It works but then after both spans are touching there is a margin on the right side of both spans that are touching. (so there is a margin on the right side of the screen even tho both span6 are touching)

Comment: Updated the post. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using grid spans if you don't need grid spans rather than overriding. If you're overriding practically every property of a class, you're better off just using a new class.

```
.half {
  margin: 0; 
  background-color: red; 
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="half">First</div>
    <div class="half">Second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cGCHa/4/